# TypeError: type_of_triangle() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'

Tags: python

```py
def type_of_triangle(a, b, c=range(0, 201)):
    if a == b and b == c:
        messagebox.showinfo("Check Triangle Type", "Your input data is\n : " + a + b + c + 'Triangle is Equilateral')

    elif 0 <= a <= 201 == 0 <= b <= 201 or 0 <= b <= 201 == 0 <= c <= 201 or 0 <= a <= 201 == 0 <= c <= 201:
        messagebox.showinfo("Check Triangle Type", "Your input data is\n : " + a + b + c + 'Triangle is Isosceles')

    elif a <= 0 or a >= 201 or b <= 0 or b >= 201 or c <= 0 or c >= 201:
        messagebox.showinfo("Check Triangle Type", "Your input data is\n : " + a + b + c + 'Out of range' + '\nEnter Integer Number between 1-200')

    elif a+b <= c or a+c <= b or b+c <= a:
        messagebox.showinfo("Check Triangle Type", "Your input data is\n : " + a + b + c + 'Not a Triangle')

    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Check Triangle Type", "Your input data is\n : " + a + b + c + 'Triangle is Scalane')

Button(window, text=" Done ", command=type_of_triangle()).grid(row=5, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

```
TypeError: type_of_triangle() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'a' and 'b'
```

Comment: `command=type_of_triangle()` - you're calling the function (indeed with no arguments) and passing the _result_ as the `command`.

Comment: the function is gonna throw an error if You don't provide c argument too because c is of type range and You are evaluating it against integers (which are of type int (short for integer))

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in parameters but the current way you've done it you cannot so the correct way is to use a lambda.

```
btn = Button(window, text=" Done ", command=lambda: type_of_triangle(a, b)).grid(row=5, column=1)
```

Comment: c argument has to be provided too given the current state of that function, otherwise it will throw an error (Your code is correct and it is a great approach, the OP just has made a mistake if they even know that)